# Create Custom extension for the Reports

Tags: magento2

To generate a new report, the admin selects 1 or more products and/or 1 or more categories, sets the (order) date from and date to. create custom Reports extension for this any idea related to this

Answer (score 0):

This is very vague question.

Can you try Studying `Magento\Reports` extension. It very `separate module.` You can easily catch up with this.

Then I would suggest you if you stuck somewhere, surely ask that question `precisely.` so I can answer you.